# How Can I position this element so it will stay stuck to the top right corner?

Tags: wordpress, search, positioning

I'm working off of a wordpress theme, and I can't seem to get the positioning of the Search Search Bar to be positioned in the desired area.  Is this not something I can achieve with positioning??

Comment: which element do you want to position in right corner?

Comment: The search bar.  Thanks bingjie2680 :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have the Css like this:

```
 #searchform {
    position:absolute;
    top: 60px;
    left: 930px;
}
```

you need to change the left value to something like 880px

Comment: That doesn't work, if you expand / contract your browser window it moves with the window, it won't stay relative to the page wrap.

Comment: Add position relative to your .builder-container-outer-wrapper and set a right offset rather than left.